# Angular matSelect not populating

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I am trying to use matSelect Version 7.3.7.
The problem is that it doesn't populate (or just doesn't open?). It doesn't matter if I populate from an array or if I add the options manually. When I click on the select box it doesn't open. Pages has values in it. When I inspect the html it doesn't have the options under the mat-select tag.

A simplified version here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jrqehn

The code looks like this:

HTML-file

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="pages">
          <mat-label>Välj system</mat-label>
          <mat-select [(value)]="computerGuid">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let page of pages" [value]="page.pageGuid">
              {{page.name}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Component (simplified)

```
pages: PageModel[] = [];

export interface PageModel {
  pageGuid: string;
  name: string;
}

ngOnInit() {
 this.pageService.getPages().subscribe(res => {
  this.pages = res;
  this.spinner.hide();
});
}
```

Module

```
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { NgxSmartModalModule } from 'ngx-smart-modal';
import { NgxSpinnerModule } from 'ngx-spinner';

import { LoginRoutingModule } from './login-routing.module';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { TagService } from '../../shared';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    LoginRoutingModule,
    BsDropdownModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NgxSpinnerModule,
    NgxSmartModalModule.forChild(),
  ],
  providers: [TagService, CookieService],
  declarations: [LoginComponent]
})
export class LoginModule { }
```

[image: console log]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you checked the console?

Comment: Yes, it is empty. Unfortunately.

Comment: can you show `console.log(this.pages)` response

Comment: or how did you defined `this.pages`?

Comment: Note: `this.spinner.hide();` this line wont work becuase its a async call so until your data being loaded the the flow control have already moved to the next line

Comment: @Fred It would be better if you setup a stackblitz with the dummy API call to get help sooner!

Comment: What about if `pages` is empty?

Comment: Pages has values. I added a picture of it and I also added pages declaration in the code.

Comment: I've never used Stackblitz but I am looking in to it now.

Comment: Set up a https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jrqehn I am missing something simple I am guessing. I get the same "error" here.

Comment: Did you see the errors in the console of Stackblitz?

Comment: Yeah, fixed it now and it is working there. :(

Comment: @Fred So it is fixed in your code? Else provide the code where I/we can reproduce an issue!

Comment: browseranimationmodule was missing in imports, please add that, it should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the Solution [Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jfyjpi)

The problem is because you have missed adding browser animation module in app module and

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

in styles.css/scss
Hope it helps!